# How to check if a string is in a list of strings with a minimal disk/space usage?

Tags: sql, string, list

I have encountered a question that need to compare a string to a list of strings and determine if this string is in the list(For example, check if string 'abc' is in a list of strings ['ab','bc','abc']). The problem is straight forward given the assumption that I store the whole list in clear text. But when the list gets bigger, say a few million/billion records, it takes a lot of space to store the list(especially if I need to do this regularly with different lists). Is there anyway to do this efficiently using a minimum storage space(that I don't need to store the whole list)?

(Specifically my question would be doing this in SQL table, so I have to store this column and properly index it for efficiency purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) Data Structure - it's designed for exactly what you're trying to accomplish with minimal space, and fast look up. Here's an article (you can find many more by searching) [Trie Prefix](http://exceptional-code.blogspot.com/2011/07/coding-up-trie-prefix-tree.html)

I'm not sure how this works with your goals of storing all your options in SQL - you could store the Trie data structure in the database